# Parse HTML targeted links, thumbnails, div class from website link

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-studio

I want to parse a html website using json group, But the problem is I couldn't found any understanding tutorials that will make it easier to learn. I want to output my targeted links, titles, thumbnail and div class. 
I don't know how to do that, but I've just created something like the below code.

```
MainActivity.java

package net.gurujibd.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private TextView results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getWebsite();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getWebsite(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.grameenphone.com/personal/offers").get();
                    builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String title = doc.title();
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                    Element masthead = doc.select(".thumbnail-wrapper").first();
                    for (Element link : links){
                        builder.append("\n").append("Link :").append(link.attr("href"))
                                .append("\n").append("Text :").append(link.text());

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    builder.append("Error:").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");

                }
                final StringBuilder finalBuilder = builder;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        results.setText(finalBuilder.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();


    }
}
```

Could please explain to me how to do that? This is my targeted [Link](https://www.grameenphone.com/personal/offers)

i want to get data from all offers section such as **Internet Offers**, **Voice Offers**, **Device Offers** etc. and it will display into my android app with GridView Layout.

If you can, please refer some useful links. Thanks